# How to group HTML table entries with summary row above detail rows with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am still learning about programming and D3, so bear with me here.

I have a table that has been generated with D3 from JSON data. What I am hoping to do next is put a summary row above detail ones for entries of the same is number but different dates.  I have a reducer function that works to show the sums of each entry, but not sure how to append that to the table above the details to result in something like:

[image: mockup]

I have a reduction working that has the summary ready, so how would I append that to my table that is working now with the detail data?  I am thinking we must use `nest` but not entirely sure what path to take.  The code I have is below:

```
const merged = [{
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "Foo - 6480_1925",
"affiliateId": "6480",
"Clicks": 6,
"Conversions": 0,
"Spend": 0.5019512028,
"affiliate": "Y_Foo_6480",
"revenue": 58.22,
"advertiser": "sky",
"spend": 0.5,
"profit": 57.72,
"profitMargin": "99",
"cpc": 0.08,
"rpc": 9.7,
"rpa": ""
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "Bar Mutual - 7157_2020",
"affiliateId": "7157",
"Clicks": 583,
"Conversions": 0,
"Spend": 166.0008698087,
"affiliate": "Y_Bar Mutual_7157",
"revenue": 2.22,
"advertiser": "Bar Mutual Insurance",
"spend": 166,
"profit": -163.78,
"profitMargin": "-7378",
"cpc": 0.28,
"rpc": 0,
"rpa": ""
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - Baz Deals - CAN - 4086_1743",
"affiliateId": "4086",
"Clicks": 1,
"Conversions": 0,
"Spend": 0.0108815003,
"affiliate": "Y_Mobile_OMBaz_CAN_4086",
"revenue": "",
"advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
"spend": 0.01,
"profit": -0.01,
"cpc": 0.01,
"rpc": 0,
"rpa": ""
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - GetStuff - 7191_2133",
"affiliateId": "7191",
"Clicks": 6,
"Conversions": 0,
"Spend": 1.3499999642,
"affiliate": "Y_GetStuff_7191",
"revenue": 0.36,
"advertiser": "Art",
"spend": 1.35,
"profit": -0.99,
"profitMargin": "-275",
"cpc": 0.22,
"rpc": 0.06,
"rpa": ""
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - Lawyer - 7275_2165",
"affiliateId": "7275",
"Clicks": 199,
"Conversions": 0,
"Spend": 10.2255493868,
"affiliate": "Y_Lawyer_7275",
"revenue": "",
"advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
"spend": 10.23,
"profit": -10.23,
"cpc": 0.06,
"rpc": 0,
"rpa": ""
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - 4735_2092",
"affiliateId": "4735",
"Clicks": 200,
"Conversions": 34,
"Spend": 59.1212777495,
"affiliate": "Y_Mobile-3B_OMNewCar_4735",
"revenue": 20.1,
"advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
"spend": 59.12,
"profit": -39.02,
"profitMargin": "-194",
"cpc": 0.3,
"rpc": 0.1,
"rpa": 0.59
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - 6586_2092",
"affiliateId": "6586",
"Clicks": 472,
"Conversions": 79,
"Spend": 61.0002093334,
"affiliate": "Y_New Cars_6586",
"revenue": 0.75,
"advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
"spend": 61,
"profit": -60.25,
"profitMargin": "-8033",
"cpc": 0.13,
"rpc": 0,
"rpa": 0.01
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - 6618_2092",
"affiliateId": "6618",
"Clicks": 2,
"Conversions": 1,
"Spend": 0.2018772066,
"affiliate": "Y_New Cars_6618",
"revenue": "",
"advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
"spend": 0.2,
"profit": -0.2,
"cpc": 0.1,
"rpc": 0,
"rpa": 0
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - 7247_1773",
"affiliateId": "7247",
"Clicks": 76,
"Conversions": 7,
"Spend": 13.9912065665,
"affiliate": "Y_New Cars_7247",
"revenue": "",
"advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
"spend": 13.99,
"profit": -13.99,
"cpc": 0.18,
"rpc": 0,
"rpa": 0
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - NSConvLAL - 6594_2092",
"affiliateId": "6594",
"Clicks": 905,
"Conversions": 264,
"Spend": 293.5172631741,
"affiliate": "Y_New Cars_6594",
"revenue": 1.72,
"advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
"spend": 293.64,
"profit": -291.8,
"profitMargin": "-16965",
"cpc": 0.32,
"rpc": 0,
"rpa": 0.01
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - NSConvLAL - 7251_2092",
"affiliateId": "7251",
"Clicks": 202,
"Conversions": 1,
"Spend": 64.9944748056,
"affiliate": "Y_New Cars_7251",
"revenue": "",
"advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
"spend": 64.99,
"profit": -64.99,
"cpc": 0.26,
"rpc": 0,
"rpa": 0
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - Span/Eng - 7165_1773",
"affiliateId": "7165",
"Clicks": 891,
"Conversions": 49,
"Spend": 74.5347691271,
"affiliate": "Y_New Cars_7165",
"revenue": "",
"advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
"spend": 74.53,
"profit": -74.53,
"cpc": 0.08,
"rpc": 0,
"rpa": 0
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - New Cars - 4713_1875",
"affiliateId": "4713",
"Clicks": 1084,
"Conversions": 326,
"Spend": 64.7100853845,
"affiliate": "Y_New Cars_4713",
"revenue": "",
"advertiser": "Umbrella",
"spend": 64.71,
"profit": -64.71,
"cpc": 0.05,
"rpc": 0,
"rpa": 0
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - New Cars - 7259_1875",
"affiliateId": "7259",
"Clicks": 1568,
"Conversions": 173,
"Spend": 51.5844874121,
"affiliate": "Y_New Cars_7259",
"revenue": "",
"advertiser": "Umbrella",
"spend": 51.58,
"profit": -51.58,
"cpc": 0.03,
"rpc": 0,
"rpa": 0
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - Destination - 7221_2068",
"affiliateId": "7221",
"Clicks": 75,
"Conversions": 0,
"Spend": 4.9945735649,
"affiliate": "Y_Destination_7221",
"revenue": 1.5,
"advertiser": "L-health",
"spend": 4.99,
"profit": -3.17,
"profitMargin": "-212",
"cpc": 0.06,
"rpc": 0.02,
"rpa": ""
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - Product - 7243_1791",
"affiliateId": "7243",
"Clicks": 36,
"Conversions": 0,
"Spend": 1.201965495,
"affiliate": "Y_Product_7243",
"revenue": 0.07,
"advertiser": "Product Tubs",
"spend": 1.2,
"profit": -1.13,
"profitMargin": "-1617",
"cpc": 0.03,
"rpc": 0,
"rpa": ""
}, {
"date": "2018-10-09",
"Campaign_Name": "test - Homewares - 7269_2163",
"affiliateId": "7269",
"Clicks": 11,
"Conversions": 0,
"Spend": 0.5186665021,
"affiliate": "Y_Homewares_7269",
"revenue": "",
"advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
"spend": 0.64,
"profit": -0.64,
"cpc": 0.05,
"rpc": 0,
"rpa": ""
}]
const columnHeaderMap = {
            Date: "date",
            AffiliateId: "affiliateId",
            Spend: "spend",
            Revenue: "revenue",
            CPC: "cpc",
            RPC: "rpc",
            RPA: "rpa",
            Profit: "profit",
            PM: "profitMargin",
            Campaign: "Campaign_Name",
            Affiliate: "affiliate"
        };

        const headers = Object.keys(columnHeaderMap);
        const columns = headers.map(header => columnHeaderMap[header]);

        const getHeaderWithColumn = column => {
            for (let header in columnHeaderMap) {
                if (columnHeaderMap[header] === column) {
                    return header;
                }
            }
        };

        // // setup the area for the table
        d3.selectAll('table').data([0]).enter().append('table');
        var table1 = d3.select('#table');

        table1.selectAll('thead').data([0]).enter().append('thead');
        var thead = table1.select('thead');

        table1.selectAll('tbody').data([0]).enter().append('tbody');
        var tbody = table1.select('tbody');

        var pmColorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
            .domain([0, 20])
            .range(['red', '#FDE541', 'green']);

        //   // append the header row
        thead.append('tr')
            .selectAll('th')
            .data(headers)
            .enter()
            .append('th')
            .text(function (column) {
                return column;
            })
            .on('click', function (d) {
                thead.attr('class', 'header');
                const columnName = columnHeaderMap[d];
                if (sortAscending) {
                    rows.sort((a, b) => {
                        if (d === 'PM') {
                            if (isNaN(a.profitMargin)) {
                                return a.profitMargin == 0;
                            }
                            if (isNaN(b.profitMargin)) {
                                return b.profitMargin == 0;
                            }
                            a.profitMargin = Number.parseFloat(a.profitMargin);
                            b.profitMargin = Number.parseFloat(b.profitMargin);
                            // parse the string into a float
                            // then do the sort calc
                        }
                        return b[columnHeaderMap[d]] < a[columnHeaderMap[d]] ? 1 : -1;
                    });
                    sortAscending = false;
                } else {
                    rows.sort((a, b) => {
                        if (d === 'PM') {
                            if (isNaN(a.profitMargin)) {
                                return a.profitMargin == 0;
                            }
                            if (isNaN(b.profitMargin)) {
                                return b.profitMargin == 0;
                            }
                            a.profitMargin = Number.parseFloat(a.profitMargin);
                            b.profitMargin = Number.parseFloat(b.profitMargin);

                            // parse the string into a float
                            // then do the sort calc
                        }
                        return b[columnHeaderMap[d]] > a[columnHeaderMap[d]] ? 1 : -1;
                    });
                    sortAscending = true;
                }

            });

        //  // create a row for each object in the data
        var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
            .data(merged)
            .enter()
            .append('tr');

        //   // create a cell in each row for each column
        var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
            .data(function (row) {
                return columns.map(function (column) {
                    return {
                        column: getHeaderWithColumn(column),
                        value: row[column],
                    };
                });
            })
            .enter()
            .append('td')
            .style("color", function (d) {
                if (d.column === 'PM') {
                    return pmColorScale(d.value);
                }

                if (d.column === 'Profit') {
                    if (d.value < 0) {
                        return "red";
                    }
                }
            }).html(function (d) {
                percentFormatter = d3.format(".0%");
                dollarFormatter = d3.format("$,");
                if (d.column === 'PM') {
                    if (!isNaN(d.value)) {
                        if (isNaN(d.value)) {
                            d.value === Number.parseInt(0);
                        }
                        return percentFormatter(d.value / 100);
                    }
                }
                if (d.column === 'Spend' || d.column === 'Revenue' || d.column === 'CPC' || d.column === 'RPC' || d.column === 'RPA' || d.column === 'Profit') {
                    if (!isNaN(d.value)) {
                        return dollarFormatter(d.value);
                    }
                }
                return d.value;
            });

        function sort(a, b) {
            if (typeof a == "string") {
                var parseA = format.parse(a);
                if (parseA) {
                    var dateA = parseA.getDate();
                    var dateB = format.parse(b).getDate();
                    return dateA > dateB ? 1 : dateA == dateB ? 0 : -1;
                } else
                    return a.localeCompare(b);
            } else if (typeof a == "number") {
                return a > b ? 1 : a == b ? 0 : -1;
            } else if (typeof a == "boolean") {
                return b ? 1 : a ? -1 : 0;
            }
        }

        // Time to make the summary 

        // // This is a subtotal reducer so each id has its total
        const summary = merged.reduce(function (val, acc) {
            if (!val[acc.affiliateId]) val[acc.affiliateId] = {
                affiliateId: acc.affiliateId,
                Spend: 0,
                revenue: 0,
                profit: 0,
                profitMargin: 0,
                Clicks: 0,
                Conversions: 0
            };
            val[acc.affiliateId].Clicks += Number.parseFloat(acc.Clicks);
            val[acc.affiliateId].Conversions += Number.parseFloat(acc.Conversions);
            val[acc.affiliateId].Spend += Number.parseFloat(acc.Spend);
            val[acc.affiliateId].revenue += Number.parseFloat(acc.revenue);
            val[acc.affiliateId].profit += Number.parseFloat(acc.profit);
            val[acc.affiliateId].Campaign_Name = acc.Campaign_Name;
            val[acc.affiliateId].affiliate = acc.affiliate;
            val[acc.affiliateId].advertiser = acc.advertiser;

            return val;
        }, {});
        // console.log(summary); // returns the array with the accumulators and ids as keys, after which I then I set to an array to look like typical JSON
          const summaryArr = [];
        for (var entry in summary) {
            // console.log(sum[entry]);
            summaryArr.push(summary[entry]);
        }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you add your data so I can use your dataset for the answer?

Comment: Sure, I updated my snippet with some data.  Thank you!

Comment: Just to check -- have you seen datatables.js? It has a lot of fancy table functionality and may serve your purposes better than something written in d3.

Comment: I have for previous projects, but it fell short on a couple things I was hoping for like trying to sort the summaries and the details in the summaries without breaking up the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `d3.nest` and a bit of data wrangling if you calculate the summary first and integrate it with the nested data. It will also be easier if you make a function for adding `td` elements (i.e. just turn the existing code into a function):

```
function addCells ( selection ) {
// create a cell in each row for each column
  selection.selectAll('td')
  .data(function(row) {
    return columns.map(function(column) {
      return {
        column: getHeaderWithColumn(column),
        value: row[column],
      };
    });
  })
  .enter()
  .append('td')
  .style("color", function(d) {
    if (d.column === 'PM') {
      return pmColorScale(d.value);
    }

    if (d.column === 'Profit') {
      if (d.value < 0) {
        return "red";
      }
    }
  }).html(function(d) {
    percentFormatter = d3.format(".0%");
    dollarFormatter = d3.format("$,");
    if (d.column === 'PM') {
      if (!isNaN(d.value)) {
        if (isNaN(d.value)) {
          d.value === Number.parseInt(0);
        }
        return percentFormatter(d.value / 100);
      }
    }
    if (d.column === 'Spend' || d.column === 'Revenue' || d.column === 'CPC' || d.column === 'RPC' || d.column === 'RPA' || d.column === 'Profit') {
      if (!isNaN(d.value)) {
        return dollarFormatter(d.value);
      }
    }
    return d.value;
  });
}
```

Tables can have any number of `tbody` elements, so we can take advantage of that and add a separate `tbody` for each set of rows representing an affiliate.

First, calculate the summary:

```
const summary = merged.reduce(function(val, acc) {
  if (!val[acc.affiliateId]) val[acc.affiliateId] = {
    affiliateId: acc.affiliateId,
    Spend: 0,
    revenue: 0,
    profit: 0,
    profitMargin: 0,
    Clicks: 0,
    Conversions: 0
  };
  val[acc.affiliateId].Clicks += Number.parseFloat(acc.Clicks);
  val[acc.affiliateId].Conversions += Number.parseFloat(acc.Conversions);
  val[acc.affiliateId].Spend += Number.parseFloat(acc.Spend);
  val[acc.affiliateId].revenue += Number.parseFloat(acc.revenue);
  val[acc.affiliateId].profit += Number.parseFloat(acc.profit);
  val[acc.affiliateId].Campaign_Name = acc.Campaign_Name;
  val[acc.affiliateId].affiliate = acc.affiliate;
  val[acc.affiliateId].advertiser = acc.advertiser;

  return val;
}, {});
```

Nest the data using the `affiliateId` as the key, and integrate the `summary` data into the nested data:

```
const nested = d3.nest()
.key( d => d.affiliateId )
.entries(merged)
.map( d => { d.header = summary[d.key]; return d } );
```

`nested` is now an array with entries that look like this:

```
{key: "6480", 
 values: [Array], // rows with affiliateId 6480 
 header: Object   // collated data on 6480 from `summary`
}
```

Bind that to the table and add a `tbody` for each entry:

```
var tbody = table1.selectAll('tbody')
  .data(nested)
  .enter()
  .append('tbody');
```

Add rows for the summary data by taking the header from the bound data. Note that d3 needs data to be in an array, so we return the header data as a single-element array. Give the row a class to distinguish it from the monthly data that we'll add next.

```
var summaryRow = tbody
  .selectAll('tr.summary')
  .data(function(d) { return [d.header] })
  .enter()
  .append('tr')
  .classed('summary',true)
```

Add the `td` elements for the row:

```
addCells(summary)
```

Now you can do the same with the rows for the monthly datasets, which `d3.nest` has put in `d.values`. Add the rows and then add the cells to the rows:

```
var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr.entry')
  .data(d => {
    return d.values
  })
  .enter()
  .append('tr')
  .classed('entry', true)

addCells(rows);
```

Full demo with some fake data:

```js
function go() {

const merged = [{
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "Foo - 6480_1925",
  "affiliateId": "6480",
  "Clicks": 6,
  "Conversions": 0,
  "Spend": 0.5019512028,
  "affiliate": "Y_Foo_6480",
  "revenue": 58.22,
  "advertiser": "sky",
  "spend": 0.5,
  "profit": 57.72,
  "profitMargin": "99",
  "cpc": 0.08,
  "rpc": 9.7,
  "rpa": ""
}, {
  "date": "2018-09-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "Foo - 6480_1925",
  "affiliateId": "6480",
  "Clicks": 6,
  "Conversions": 0,
  "Spend": 0.5019512028,
  "affiliate": "Y_Foo_6480",
  "revenue": 58.22,
  "advertiser": "sky",
  "spend": 0.5,
  "profit": 57.72,
  "profitMargin": "99",
  "cpc": 0.08,
  "rpc": 9.7,
  "rpa": ""
}, {
  "date": "2018-08-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "Foo - 6480_1925",
  "affiliateId": "6480",
  "Clicks": 6,
  "Conversions": 0,
  "Spend": 0.5019512028,
  "affiliate": "Y_Foo_6480",
  "revenue": 58.22,
  "advertiser": "sky",
  "spend": 0.5,
  "profit": 57.72,
  "profitMargin": "99",
  "cpc": 0.08,
  "rpc": 9.7,
  "rpa": ""
}, {
  "date": "2018-07-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "Foo - 6480_1925",
  "affiliateId": "6480",
  "Clicks": 6,
  "Conversions": 0,
  "Spend": 0.5019512028,
  "affiliate": "Y_Foo_6480",
  "revenue": 58.22,
  "advertiser": "sky",
  "spend": 0.5,
  "profit": 57.72,
  "profitMargin": "99",
  "cpc": 0.08,
  "rpc": 9.7,
  "rpa": ""
}, {
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "Bar Mutual - 7157_2020",
  "affiliateId": "7157",
  "Clicks": 583,
  "Conversions": 0,
  "Spend": 166.0008698087,
  "affiliate": "Y_GetStuff_7191",
  "revenue": 2.22,
  "advertiser": "Bar Mutual Insurance",
  "spend": 166,
  "profit": -163.78,
  "profitMargin": "-7378",
  "cpc": 0.28,
  "rpc": 0,
  "rpa": ""
}, {
  "date": "2018-09-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "Bar Mutual - 7157_2020",
  "affiliateId": "7157",
  "Clicks": 1,
  "Conversions": 0,
  "Spend": 0.0108815003,
  "affiliate": "Y_GetStuff_7191",
  "revenue": "",
  "advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
  "spend": 0.01,
  "profit": -0.01,
  "cpc": 0.01,
  "rpc": 0,
  "rpa": ""
}, {
  "date": "2018-08-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "Bar Mutual - 7157_2020",
  "affiliateId": "7157",
  "Clicks": 6,
  "Conversions": 0,
  "Spend": 1.3499999642,
  "affiliate": "Y_GetStuff_7191",
  "revenue": 0.36,
  "advertiser": "Art",
  "spend": 1.35,
  "profit": -0.99,
  "profitMargin": "-275",
  "cpc": 0.22,
  "rpc": 0.06,
  "rpa": ""
}, {
  "date": "2018-07-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "Bar Mutual - 7157_2020",
  "affiliateId": "7157",
  "Clicks": 199,
  "Conversions": 0,
  "Spend": 10.2255493868,
  "affiliate": "Y_GetStuff_7191",
  "revenue": "",
  "advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
  "spend": 10.23,
  "profit": -10.23,
  "cpc": 0.06,
  "rpc": 0,
  "rpa": ""
}, {
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - 4735_2092",
  "affiliateId": "4735",
  "Clicks": 200,
  "Conversions": 34,
  "Spend": 59.1212777495,
  "affiliate": "Y_Mobile-3B_OMNewCar_4735",
  "revenue": 20.1,
  "advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
  "spend": 59.12,
  "profit": -39.02,
  "profitMargin": "-194",
  "cpc": 0.3,
  "rpc": 0.1,
  "rpa": 0.59
}, {
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - 6586_2092",
  "affiliateId": "6586",
  "Clicks": 472,
  "Conversions": 79,
  "Spend": 61.0002093334,
  "affiliate": "Y_New Cars_6586",
  "revenue": 0.75,
  "advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
  "spend": 61,
  "profit": -60.25,
  "profitMargin": "-8033",
  "cpc": 0.13,
  "rpc": 0,
  "rpa": 0.01
}, {
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - 6618_2092",
  "affiliateId": "6618",
  "Clicks": 2,
  "Conversions": 1,
  "Spend": 0.2018772066,
  "affiliate": "Y_New Cars_6618",
  "revenue": "",
  "advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
  "spend": 0.2,
  "profit": -0.2,
  "cpc": 0.1,
  "rpc": 0,
  "rpa": 0
}, {
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - 7247_1773",
  "affiliateId": "7247",
  "Clicks": 76,
  "Conversions": 7,
  "Spend": 13.9912065665,
  "affiliate": "Y_New Cars_7247",
  "revenue": "",
  "advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
  "spend": 13.99,
  "profit": -13.99,
  "cpc": 0.18,
  "rpc": 0,
  "rpa": 0
}, {
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - NSConvLAL - 6594_2092",
  "affiliateId": "6594",
  "Clicks": 905,
  "Conversions": 264,
  "Spend": 293.5172631741,
  "affiliate": "Y_New Cars_6594",
  "revenue": 1.72,
  "advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
  "spend": 293.64,
  "profit": -291.8,
  "profitMargin": "-16965",
  "cpc": 0.32,
  "rpc": 0,
  "rpa": 0.01
}, {
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - NSConvLAL - 7251_2092",
  "affiliateId": "7251",
  "Clicks": 202,
  "Conversions": 1,
  "Spend": 64.9944748056,
  "affiliate": "Y_New Cars_7251",
  "revenue": "",
  "advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
  "spend": 64.99,
  "profit": -64.99,
  "cpc": 0.26,
  "rpc": 0,
  "rpa": 0
}, {
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "test - NS - New Cars - Span/Eng - 7165_1773",
  "affiliateId": "7165",
  "Clicks": 891,
  "Conversions": 49,
  "Spend": 74.5347691271,
  "affiliate": "Y_New Cars_7165",
  "revenue": "",
  "advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
  "spend": 74.53,
  "profit": -74.53,
  "cpc": 0.08,
  "rpc": 0,
  "rpa": 0
}, {
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "test - New Cars - 4713_1875",
  "affiliateId": "4713",
  "Clicks": 1084,
  "Conversions": 326,
  "Spend": 64.7100853845,
  "affiliate": "Y_New Cars_4713",
  "revenue": "",
  "advertiser": "Umbrella",
  "spend": 64.71,
  "profit": -64.71,
  "cpc": 0.05,
  "rpc": 0,
  "rpa": 0
}, {
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "test - New Cars - 7259_1875",
  "affiliateId": "7259",
  "Clicks": 1568,
  "Conversions": 173,
  "Spend": 51.5844874121,
  "affiliate": "Y_New Cars_7259",
  "revenue": "",
  "advertiser": "Umbrella",
  "spend": 51.58,
  "profit": -51.58,
  "cpc": 0.03,
  "rpc": 0,
  "rpa": 0
}, {
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "test - Destination - 7221_2068",
  "affiliateId": "7221",
  "Clicks": 75,
  "Conversions": 0,
  "Spend": 4.9945735649,
  "affiliate": "Y_Destination_7221",
  "revenue": 1.5,
  "advertiser": "L-health",
  "spend": 4.99,
  "profit": -3.17,
  "profitMargin": "-212",
  "cpc": 0.06,
  "rpc": 0.02,
  "rpa": ""
}, {
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "test - Product - 7243_1791",
  "affiliateId": "7243",
  "Clicks": 36,
  "Conversions": 0,
  "Spend": 1.201965495,
  "affiliate": "Y_Product_7243",
  "revenue": 0.07,
  "advertiser": "Product Tubs",
  "spend": 1.2,
  "profit": -1.13,
  "profitMargin": "-1617",
  "cpc": 0.03,
  "rpc": 0,
  "rpa": ""
}, {
  "date": "2018-10-09",
  "Campaign_Name": "test - Homewares - 7269_2163",
  "affiliateId": "7269",
  "Clicks": 11,
  "Conversions": 0,
  "Spend": 0.5186665021,
  "affiliate": "Y_Homewares_7269",
  "revenue": "",
  "advertiser": "Acme, Inc. ",
  "spend": 0.64,
  "profit": -0.64,
  "cpc": 0.05,
  "rpc": 0,
  "rpa": ""
}]
const columnHeaderMap = {
  Date: "date",
  AffiliateId: "affiliateId",
  Spend: "spend",
  Revenue: "revenue",
  CPC: "cpc",
  RPC: "rpc",
  RPA: "rpa",
  Profit: "profit",
  PM: "profitMargin",
  Campaign: "Campaign_Name",
  Affiliate: "affiliate"
};

const headers = Object.keys(columnHeaderMap);
const columns = headers.map(header => columnHeaderMap[header]);

const getHeaderWithColumn = column => {
  for (let header in columnHeaderMap) {
    if (columnHeaderMap[header] === column) {
      return header;
    }
  }
};

var pmColorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
  .domain([0, 20])
  .range(['red', '#FDE541', 'green']);



// // setup the area for the table
// d3.selectAll('table').data([0]).enter().append('table');
var table1 = d3.select('#table');

table1.selectAll('thead').data([0]).enter().append('thead');
var thead = table1.select('thead');

//   // append the header row
thead.append('tr')
  .selectAll('th')
  .data(headers)
  .enter()
  .append('th')
  .text(function(column) {
    return column;
  })
  .on('click', function(d) {
    thead.attr('class', 'header');
    const columnName = columnHeaderMap[d];
    if (sortAscending) {
      rows.sort((a, b) => {
        if (d === 'PM') {
          if (isNaN(a.profitMargin)) {
            return a.profitMargin == 0;
          }
          if (isNaN(b.profitMargin)) {
            return b.profitMargin == 0;
          }
          a.profitMargin = Number.parseFloat(a.profitMargin);
          b.profitMargin = Number.parseFloat(b.profitMargin);
          // parse the string into a float
          // then do the sort calc
        }
        return b[columnHeaderMap[d]] < a[columnHeaderMap[d]] ? 1 : -1;
      });
      sortAscending = false;
    } else {
      rows.sort((a, b) => {
        if (d === 'PM') {
          if (isNaN(a.profitMargin)) {
            return a.profitMargin == 0;
          }
          if (isNaN(b.profitMargin)) {
            return b.profitMargin == 0;
          }
          a.profitMargin = Number.parseFloat(a.profitMargin);
          b.profitMargin = Number.parseFloat(b.profitMargin);

          // parse the string into a float
          // then do the sort calc
        }
        return b[columnHeaderMap[d]] > a[columnHeaderMap[d]] ? 1 : -1;
      });
      sortAscending = true;
    }

  });

// Time to make the summary

// // This is a subtotal reducer so each id has its total
const summary = merged.reduce(function(val, acc) {
  if (!val[acc.affiliateId]) val[acc.affiliateId] = {
    affiliateId: acc.affiliateId,
    Spend: 0,
    revenue: 0,
    profit: 0,
    profitMargin: 0,
    Clicks: 0,
    Conversions: 0
  };
  val[acc.affiliateId].Clicks += Number.parseFloat(acc.Clicks);
  val[acc.affiliateId].Conversions += Number.parseFloat(acc.Conversions);
  val[acc.affiliateId].Spend += Number.parseFloat(acc.Spend);
  val[acc.affiliateId].revenue += Number.parseFloat(acc.revenue);
  val[acc.affiliateId].profit += Number.parseFloat(acc.profit);
  val[acc.affiliateId].Campaign_Name = acc.Campaign_Name;
  val[acc.affiliateId].affiliate = acc.affiliate;
  val[acc.affiliateId].advertiser = acc.advertiser;

  return val;
}, {});

const nested = d3.nest()
.key( d => d.affiliateId )
.entries(merged)
.map( d => { d.header = summary[d.key]; return d } );


var tbody = table1.selectAll('tbody')
  .data(nested)
  .enter()
    .append('tbody');

var summaryRow = tbody
  .selectAll('tr.summary')
  .data(d => [d.header])
  .enter()
  .append('tr')
  .classed('summary',true)

addCells(summaryRow)


// create a row for each object in the data
var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr.entry')
  .data(d => {
    return d.values
  })
  .enter()
  .append('tr')
  .classed('entry', true)

addCells(rows);

function addCells ( selection ) {
// create a cell in each row for each column
  selection.selectAll('td')
  .data(function(row) {
    return columns.map(function(column) {
      return {
        column: getHeaderWithColumn(column),
        value: row[column],
      };
    });
  })
  .enter()
  .append('td')
  .style("color", function(d) {
    if (d.column === 'PM') {
      return pmColorScale(d.value);
    }

    if (d.column === 'Profit') {
      if (d.value < 0) {
        return "red";
      }
    }
  }).html(function(d) {
    percentFormatter = d3.format(".0%");
    dollarFormatter = d3.format("$,");
    if (d.column === 'PM') {
      if (!isNaN(d.value)) {
        if (isNaN(d.value)) {
          d.value === Number.parseInt(0);
        }
        return percentFormatter(d.value / 100);
      }
    }
    if (d.column === 'Spend' || d.column === 'Revenue' || d.column === 'CPC' || d.column === 'RPC' || d.column === 'RPA' || d.column === 'Profit') {
      if (!isNaN(d.value)) {
        return dollarFormatter(d.value);
      }
    }
    return d.value;
  });
}

function sort(a, b) {
  if (typeof a == "string") {
    var parseA = format.parse(a);
    if (parseA) {
      var dateA = parseA.getDate();
      var dateB = format.parse(b).getDate();
      return dateA > dateB ? 1 : dateA == dateB ? 0 : -1;
    } else
      return a.localeCompare(b);
  } else if (typeof a == "number") {
    return a > b ? 1 : a == b ? 0 : -1;
  } else if (typeof a == "boolean") {
    return b ? 1 : a ? -1 : 0;
  }
}


}
window.onload = go;
```

```css
.summary td {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: aliceblue; 
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>  

<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: This is fantastic.  I seem to get a couple bugs like positive totals being NaN and sometimes not all the rows load when it draws the first time, but it's a great way to see how you do this.  Well done.

Comment: If you're getting NaN values, you could do some extra sanity checks in the code that creates the table summary to make sure that all incoming values are what you expect them to be and there's not something there that is throwing things off. You probably also want to format all your dollar values to display to two decimal places using `Number.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: I am also seeing a bug where on the second, fourth, and even drawings of the table, it also only renders some of the entries with their summaries.  On odd drawings, it draws it all perfectly.  This happens when there are the individual tbody elements drawn, but with rows drawn instead of  a `tbody` for each entry it works right, but that of course presents the same problem as the previous comment of going against the magic of nested tables.  Guess that's probably a whole separate question though since we grouped and nested but this is something in the DOM.

Comment: It would be possible to do the table with rows and not tbody elements, but it does make it a PITA for just about everything. datatables.js is probably the best JS table solution out there, and even it doesn't really have all the grouping/summary features that people want.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like it is.  Bet there's a hybrid that I can make using the two.  Thanks for the suggestion.  The inner sorting works well, so I bet datatables might be able to do the outer.